# How can I tell what is dirty in my modal form?

Tags: abp

In my  ABP 4.2 Angular project I've added got a modal with two form groups in it. When you save the modal I'm firing the data off via my service proxy and I want the form to remain open so the user can continue editing. To achieve this I've removed the default `tap(() => this.hideForm())` that ABP adds by default. I'm calling `this.form1.markAsPristine()` and `this.form2.markAsPristine()` but when I click the Cancel button after the Save has completed I still get the Confirmation modal telling me I've got unsaved changes. How can I tell what is causing this Confirmation modal to fire? How can I find out what pending changes I still have in the modal?